# C# DateTimePicker without time in .Value

Tags: c#, .net

When user selects a date using DateTimePicker, it comes with the current time in the value.  I wish to set the time to 0:00.  The kludge I came up with is as follows, but I feel like their has to be an easier way.

```
DateTime d, t;
t = dateTimePicker1.Value; 
// instantiating a DateTime object using this overload sets time to 00:00:00
d = new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, t.Day);
```

Comment: Do you want the time to not show up in the DateTimePicker?  Or do you just want whatever the user picks to not include a time?  `DateTime` has a property called [`.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives you the Date and the time portion set to 0

Comment: `t = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date`

Comment: As an aside, another potential gotcha for the DateTimePicker is that it is initialized to `DateTime.Now`, which has `DateTimeKind.Local` whereas if a user selects a date, it has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.   In some applications this can be significant, so you may need to force the Kind property as well as truncating the time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the DateTime.Date property:

```
t = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

Date is another representation of a "classic" datetime (which is what you are using), with the time part initialized to 00:00:00

Comment: Its great that you have posted an answer but it really helps everyone if you explained why your answer is correct.  Pretend I don't know (OP surely doesn't).  What is `.Date`?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Date is another representation of a "classic" datetime (which is what OP was using), with the time part initialized to 00:00:00 .

Comment: You need to update your answer, not add detail in the comments

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have a data type that is designed to contain a Date. It only has DateTime. It serves double purpose: when you need to express just a date, it is stored as a DateTime with the time portion set to 0:00.

There is no way to "get rid" of the time portion. If you don't want to *see* it, just format the DateTime without the hours, minutes, and seconds. You will need to do this no matter how many times you "get rid" of the time by using DateTime.Date, (which will just return another DateTime with the time portion set to 0:00).

Comment: That is a method, not a data type. The result is another DateTime with the time zeroed out, which per the OP's post would be identical to the input.

Comment: Technically its a _property_, but the OP only indicated `"I wish to set the time to 0:00."` which using the property `.Date` would give them.